# How to do Guid.TryParse in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query like:

```
from rd in registrantContext.RegistrantData
join c in registrantContext.Components    
...
select new
{
    RegistrantID = r.SortingId,
    FieldID = c.SortingId,
    FieldValue = (!Guid.TryParse(rd.Value, out guidValue) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(rd.Value)) ? rd.Value :
        (c is IComponentItemParent) ? (c as IComponentItemParent).Children.FirstOrDefault(i => i.UId == guidValue).LabelText : rd.Value,
...
}
```

But I got error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
>   TryParse(System.String, System.Guid ByRef)' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression.

I'd like to know how to do Guid.TryParse the linq query, perhaps like SqlFunctions.

Comment: You'll have to load everything in memory first and then project the `select` clause. LINQ to Entities doesn't understand `Guid.TryParse`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Or do the parsing outside of the LINQ query and then just do a normal comparison.

Comment: @TiesonT. How will he do the parsing beforehand if he's relaying on data projected from the query?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Ah, I missed that `rd` comes from the first part of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break your query into two parts. First, use LINQ-to-Entities to read the data from the database. Then, take the results and use regular LINQ-to-objects to select what you need - now you can use arbitrary C#  expressions without limitations of LINQ-to-entities.

Comment: How to create a helper method that returns a Guid and calling that method from your LINQ?

Comment: How to make it recognized by linq? Linq can't even run Guid.TryParse.

Comment: But that would load more data into memory which is slower and is not good if database table is big.

Comment: If you handle the data as a (potentially infinite) steam using IEnumerable<T> and avoid materializing the entire dataset at once using things like ToList(), then you might avoid memory problems. In any case, try it and measure it before worrying about hypothetical issues.

Comment: Do you mean ToList() will use more memory? I use "var list= from ...ToList()". What is the difference between IEnumerable and List or var?

Comment: IEnumerable<T> gives you a potentially infinite sequence abstraction - only a small part of the sequence needs to be in memory at any given time. List materializes the entire sequence in memory. For example, it's common for IEnumerable implementations to fetch remote data in chunks on as-needed basis. When you call ToList() on an enumerable, it'll enumerate the entire sequence to, essentially, populate an array..

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is trying to build a single SQL statement to execute for your query.  There is no equivalent to Guid.TryParse for it to build in the query.  You'll need to exclude that part of the class initializer and test for that condition after the query results are collected.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use GUID try parse in LINQ it does not recognize that method when converting to sqlqery using something like `ToList()` so it becomes in memory object

Like this (if it not a huge amount of data)

```
(from rd in registrantContext.RegistrantData
join c in registrantContext.Components select new rd, c).ToList().
Select(v=> new
{
    RegistrantID = r.SortingId,
    FieldID = c.SortingId,
    FieldValue = (!Guid.TryParse(rd.Value, out guidValue) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(rd.Value)) ? rd.Value :
        (c is IComponentItemParent) ? (c as IComponentItemParent).Children.FirstOrDefault(i => i.UId == guidValue).LabelText : rd.Value,
...
}
```